# Race condition with scipy.weave.inline

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scipy, race-condition

Recently I've begun to receive `SyntaxError`s when running parallel neural-network simulations using `brian2`.  These are being raised by calls to `scipy.weave.inline` when it tries to evaluate lines of code in a cache file.

The full description of the problem and my guess at its cause is [here](https://github.com/brian-team/brian2/issues/463).

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064806/syntaxerror-with-scipy-weave-inline) is a link to a related question I asked earlier, with a full stacktrace for one of the errors.  My answer to that question provides just a temporary solution.  (Syntax errors are re-introduced as soon as a new set of parallel runs is executed.)

Is there an easy way for me to avoid this race condition?

Comment: Just to clarify, this is a runtime `SyntaxError` that is being thrown by user code, not the python interpreter?

Comment: @amccormack the error is being raised by the interpreter -- i.e., neither my code nor `brian2` nor `scipy` explicitly raises the error.  it occurs when `eval(line)` is called within `scipy.weave`, where `line` is a line from one of the cache files.

Comment: I don't know anything about scipy, so I can't offer any insight into avoiding the actual issue. The `eval` means that it is based on code being generated on the fly, which is what I was trying to clarify so we could rule out a .py file actually having the error.

Comment: @amccormack ah, yes, i think the error points to there being garbage in the cache file.  (and, i haven't mentioned here, but it's in the question i linked to: the `SyntaxError` goes away when i delete the cache and run a single instance of my script -- i.e., without parallelization.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a known bug in `scipy`: See [this](https://github.com/ioam/topographica/issues/595) and [this](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1895) discussion on `github`.  Some workarounds are suggested in these discussions:

1) Execute a single run of the script -- so that the cache file is filled -- and then execute the other runs in parallel.  The parallel runs will not try to re-fill the cache.

2) Make a symbolic link from `/tmp` to `~/.python27_compiled`.  (I'm not sure why this would work.)

3) Use `cython` instead.